# Test custom hook with multiple async requests with jest and renderhook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-query

I've been working on an application that uses react-query for handling and caching responses to our backend. Got a lot of inspiration from the creator behind that framework to use custom hooks for handling backend states. In the beginning it was quite easy but later on the hooks started to be dependent to one and another. This resulted in some wierd behavior in the CI were some testcases failed due to heavy load on the servers. (note that backend is mocked with msw)

Custom hook containing multiple custom hooks:

```
const useFooMutation = () => {
    const cache = useQueryClient();
    const { types } = useTypes(); // async call to backend
    const { user } = useAuth(); // async call to backend

    return useMutation(['key'], mutationFunction, {
        onSuccess: async (data, variables) => {
            // Do cache handling by using values types and user
        },
    });
};
```

Test case:

```
test('useFooMutation should foo', async () => {
    const { wrapper } = setupCache();
    const { result, waitFor, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useFooMutation(), { wrapper });

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    act(() => {
        result.current.mutate({
            values
        });
    });

    await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess && !result.current.isLoading);
    expect(result.current.isSuccess).toEqual(true);
    expect(result.current.data).toEqual(fooMockData);
});
```

When I debugged the code I saw that sometimes the values from the hooks useTypes and useAuth was not yet fetched. The values from the other custom hooks are used when I do cache manipulation. So this results in some wierd behavior for some machines. For example running locally this runs ok most of the times but on a heavy loaded CI server, it results in crashes quite often.
What I've tried so far is to add a timeout before the mutation function in the test case on a timeout that seems to work, not a nice solution. And by using the waitForNextUpdate the test case works fine most of the times but not when the CI is loaded.
So I need a good way to find out when then the useFooMutation has gathered all values from the hooks its dependent on before I can call mutate()?

Comment: not sure I totally understand the question - how can a mutation not be in a "stable state"? What does it mean it depends on the values from the custom hook? Unlike a query, you have to trigger a mutation manually to do something, so I'm not sure what you need to "wait for" ?

Comment: the custom hooks (useTypes, useAuth) are used to fetch information about the user and types. The values are then used in onSuccess to manipulate the cache. So when I debug, I see that the values about the user and types are not fetched before I call the mutation function

Comment: I think an easy solution would be to pass the values for types and user in the mutate-call. But then I would need to have to hooks useTypes and useAuth everywhere I want to use the hook useFooMutation, and that feels bloated

Comment: @TkDodo I updated with more information. Thanks

Comment: how is this useFooMutation hook used in a component? Assuming you have a button that triggers the mutation, I guess the button is disabled as long as the mutation is not "ready". so you have to call `useTypes` and `useAuth` in your component and disable that button. you'd need to do the same in the test. here, it becomes apparent that you need to know that implementation detail about useFooMutation, because it doesn't show it. If the mutation also returns e.g. a `ready` flag that depends on both queries being loaded, you can check for that in your component and in the test

Comment: @TkDodo yes, that process I've managed to test. But in this case I want to just test the hook it self. Thats why I asked, if there is a way to create a custom hook who is dependent on other async custom hooks and how can one test it. :)

Comment: as I tried to say, your hook needs to expose it's "dependencies", in this case, the loading state of the dependent queries so that you can wait for it